# Force Visual Studio to use reference at path

Tags: .net, mono

I have a simple goal, but I am struggling to find a way to achieve it:

- Build my dll that uses **.NET 3.5**, (unfortunately), and **DON'T** reference **.NET 4.0** indirectly through `System.Core`.

The project is able to build and function on its own, but my test project that references it cannot build because of an indirect reference to mscorlib 4.0.0.0. I determined that the indirect reference is coming from System.Core.dll with the help of dnSpy. For some reason, the .NET 3.5 System.Core is referencing mscorlib 4.0.0.0, among other .NET 4.0 dlls.

The test project is able to build if I enable Specific Version on the reference to my main project, however what I am trying to test is to verify that everything still works even when there are version changes. Since this is a mono project, I thought I'd explicitly reference the System.Core.dll mono provides that definitely does not reference .NET 4.0 dlls, but Visual Studio just ignores the reference and uses the version in the GAC, which has the seemingly nonsensical references. If I set the System.Core reference to Specific Version, then it fails to resolve, even if I specify the version number in the .csproj file.

How can I force Visual Studio to just use the dll I'm referencing, instead of the one in the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I just discovered for myself why it's impossible to specify a specific dll to use: The assembly doesn't know. It's either a specific version, or no specific version. It seems my real problem here is the fact that MSBuild and dnSpy are both incorrectly resolving indirect dependencies to .NET 4.0 assemblies, when they shouldn't be.

So, while my problem unfortunately isn't solved, the question is answered.

Comment: I don't believe you found the answer. I cannot see `System.Core` 3.5.0.0 has any reference to `mscorlib` 4.0.0.0 (ILSpy), so I don't know what exactly came out of your investigation and why this quick conclusion.

Comment: System.Core doesn't have any reference to mscorlib 4.0.0.0, and ILSpy gets that right. However, dnSpy gets it wrong, and importantly MSBuild gets it wrong.

Comment: You have to reveal more information than a simple claim on what "gets it wrong". Deep down inside dnSpy and MSBuild have completely different backends, so I don't believe both can be wrong on the same thing. If you do have a reliable way to reproduce it, open an issue and involve Microsoft https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues

Comment: Sorry, but frankly, I really don't. I suspect it has something to do with the GAC, but I don't know for sure, and I have no way to confirm reproducibility, since it's always a problem on my PC, but I don't have other computers to try it on. Notably, .NET 3.5 applications are able to run just fine with these assemblies that supposedly use .NET 4, I just can't build them without setting "Specific Version" and pointing to one that isn't on the GAC.